# What is the difference between "..." and "[]" in Android Java function parameters?

Tags: java, android, parameters, optional-parameters, optional-arguments

I saw examples where one puts an array parameter to a function like this :

```
function f(String... strings)
{

}
```

and I guess this is one way of saying "expect an indefinite number of strings".

But how is it different from `String[] strings` ?

When / why / how should I use it (the three dots notation) ?

Comment: @Raghunandan Thank you ! should I close the question ?

Comment: Here's another answer for you question http://stackoverflow.com/a/7951397/1651233

Answer (score 5):

As you already guessed, the ... notation (called [varargs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html)) defines one or more parameters of the given type. In your method you will get a String[] in both cases. The difference is on the caller side.

```
public void test1(String... params) {
  // do something with the String[] params
}

public void test2(String[] params) {
  // do something with the String[] params
}

public void caller() {
  test1("abc"); // valid call results in a String[1]
  test1("abc", "def", "ghi"); // valid call results in a String[3]
  test1(new String[] {"abc", "def", ghi"}); // valid call results in a String[3]

  test2("abc"); // invalid call results in compile error
  test2("abc", "def", "ghi"); // invalid call results in compile error
  test2(new String[] {"abc", "def", ghi"}); // valid call
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The difference between them is the way you call the function. With String var args you can omit the array creation.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    callMe1(new String[] {"a", "b", "c"});
    callMe2("a", "b", "c");
    // You can also do this
    // callMe2(new String[] {"a", "b", "c"});
}

public static void callMe1(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(args.getClass() == String[].class);
    for (String s : args) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
public static void callMe2(String... args) {
    System.out.println(args.getClass() == String[].class);
    for (String s : args) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/301599/712960)

Comment: great. this is what I'm looking for. And one final thing, can I call `callMe1` with an empty array ?

Answer (score 1):

Let me try to answer your question one by one.

**Firstly** function f(String... strings) {   }
The (...) identifies a variable number of arguments which means multiple arguments.
you can pass the n number of arguments. Please refer the below example,

```
static int sum(int ... numbers)
{
   int total = 0;
   for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
      total += numbers[i];
   return total;
}
```

and you can call the function like 
sum(10,20,30,40,50,60);

**Secondly** String[] strings also similar to multiple arguments but in Java main function you can use only string array. Here you can pass the arguments through command line on run time.

```
class Sample{
     public static void main(String args[]){
        System.out.println(args.length);
     }
 }
```

> java Sample test 10 20

**Thirdly**, When and where you should use means,

Suppose you want to pass the arguments through command line also run time you can use String[] string.

Suppose you want pass n number of arguments at any time from your program or manually then you can use (...) multiple arguments.

Answer (score 0):

String... strings is as you said an indefinite number of Strings
String[] expects an array

The difference of both is, that the array has a fixed size he is initialized with.
If it is function f(String[] strings) it's just the expected parameter.