# Class constructor does not differentiate between args... and args[][]

Tags: java, oop, constructor

I am currently in the midst of writing a linear algebra library with java, inspired by my linear algebra I & II courses in school.

I want my program to be as flexible as can be, and therefor decided my `Matrix` class will have many available constructors. However, Java throws a compile error when I try to have both of these constructors together:

```
public Matrix(double[]... rows) { ... }

public Matrix(double[][] matrix) { ... }
```

I don't understand why, seeing as the first constructor will accept any number of `double[]` arrays as args: `Matrix matrix = new Matrix(r1, r2, r3... etc)` and the second constructor will only receive one `double[][]` arg: `Matrix matrix = new Matrix(arr)`. I realize that inside both constructors I will deal with the same data structure (a 2D array of doubles) but there is no ambiguity here regarding the input type, which is why this is strange to me.

Comment: Because `...` is syntactic sugar for `[]`.

Comment: "I want my program to be as flexible as can be" [YAGNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it). This sort of flexibility is like putting a pool in the back seat of your car just in case you ever need to carry a shark to the vet. Pick one consistent way of doing it, and stick to that.

Comment: Why? It makes total sense when you think of it. Think of arrays as representations of vectors, and then it makes sense to use `...`, then think of matrix multiplications and reductions, and then it makes sense to use `double[][]`, any way, this is for learning purposes and not production code so YAGNI isn't relevant here.

Comment: Matrices are logically 2d arrays. If you have a matrix method `method(double[]...)`, then you can invoke it with a 1d array argument, which may not be what you intend; and this is a type error which you couldn't make if the parameter were `double[][]`.

Comment: But in terms of YAGNI: why do you think the variadic form helps? It allows you to write `method(new double[]{1, 0}, new double[]{0, 1})`; but why choose that over `method(new double[][]{{1, 0}, {0, 1}})`, which is more concise? The only situation in which it might help is if you have pre-constructed row arrays, then you can write `method(row1, row2)`; but I can honestly say I have never (or at least rarely) needed such functionality, and I've done a fair amount of linear algebra in days gone by. Ultimately, I'm a sign, not a cop; you are under no compunction to listen.

Answer (score 1):

`Type...` is equivalent to `Type[]` (at least as far as method parameter declaration and method implementation are concerned). In this sense, `Type[]...` is equivalent to `Type[][]`, which explains how `double[]...` is seen as `double[][]`, i.e. it's seen as same signature.

Comment: It's not equivalent: you can't call `foo(1, 2, 3)` if the method is `foo(int[])`; but you can call `foo(new int[]{1, 2, 3})` if the method is `foo(int...)`.

Comment: @AndyTurner they're equivalent in the method that declares the var-arg/array. But that's a good point. Edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

For JVM there isn't a difference between varargs (`...`) or an array (`[]`), all it sees is an array at runtime.

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/7951397/7468990